# Loadlibrary fails to load dll

Tags: visual-c++, dll

```
    *******************UseDll1.cpp*********************

        #include <windows.h>

typedef int (*function1_ptr) ();

function1_ptr function1=NULL;

int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int) { 

    HMODULE myDll = LoadLibrary("Dll1.dll"); 

    if(myDll!=NULL) {  
        function1 = (function1_ptr) GetProcAddress(myDll,"function1");  

        if(function1!=NULL)  
            function1();
        else
            exit(4);

        FreeLibrary(myDll);
    }
    else
        exit(6);

    return 0;
}
```

This is done in order to call Dll1.dll which was created with the functionality to send mail to my own mail server. The above code runs and exits,and no mail is sent.

And i also placed the Dll1.dll in the same folder as UseDll1.

EDIT:
 I added the Dll1.dll into the system32 folder.

Comment: Don't put it in the system32. It's not suppose to go there and you're just hacking around without solving the real problem.

Comment: i read in the internet wherein they are saying that there are chances that the dll is not able to load because it also has some dependencies,but in that case function1 would return NULL..wht say??

Comment: if the variable myDll is not null but GetProcAddress return null, check whether the dll is exporting required function. do take note of "name mangling" if you are exporting as c++

Answer (score 12):

Have you verify that you have all external dependencies for "DLL1.dll" ?

LoadLibrary will fail even if any of the indirect linked-library is not available.

Answer (score 7):

In my dll calling experience, I had same problem. I did everything for giving path rightly but my library can not be loaded. Firstly I thought my dll had error, but nothing solved my problem at start. I advice doing below step for friends who think their project written rightly but still having same problem:

1. Go to your DLL project and assure that you selected **Multi-threaded Debug** instead of Multi-thread(Debug) DLL(don't use dll because it uses some function from dll instead of embedding them inside) as runtime library(specially for debug mode). You can see runtime library selection under **Property>Configuration Property>C/C++>Code** Generation.
2. After our DLL file is ok, we must ensure that our project uses **right platform**. If our dll uses **x64**, our project have to use **x64**. You can control it from configuration manager and you can select right one from platform box.

After building project with right configuration, it is working now.

Answer (score 6):

Thank you very much, your web page helped me a lot :) I only had to use tchar.h to make it working. You can see it in the rest of the answer.

```
#pragma once
#include <windows.h>
#include "spinapi.h"
#include <tchar.h>

typedef int (*count_boards_ptr)(void);

int x = 0;
HINSTANCE hinstDLL;
hinstDLL = LoadLibrary(_T("C:\\Smajdalf\\doucko_C\\DLLProblem\\DLLProblem\\spinapi.dll"));
count_boards_ptr count_boards = NULL;
count_boards = (count_boards_ptr) GetProcAddress(hinstDLL, "pb_count_boards");

if(count_boards != NULL) {
    x = count_boards();
}

FreeLibrary(hinstDLL);
```

Comment: Which web page do you mean? I don't seem to find a url that you are referring to.

Answer (score 4):

Just because the code runs and exits doesn't mean it's right! Are you sure that:

- The DLL is being correctly loaded
  (myDll!=null)
- GetProcAddress is returning a valid
  pointer (function1!=null)

You should step through the code in a debugger to make sure all this is happening and that the code does get to **function1()**. If it does then my guess would be that your email function has a bug in it.

Comment: mydll is returning NULL...How do i fix it..?? i have the DLL in the same folder as the place from where this code runs

Comment: I'm assuming you don't run your app from system32, so just remove the path from the call to LoadLibrary so that it reads LoadLibrary("Dll1.dll") and see what happens...

Answer (score 1):

Why not debug it and see where it fails? Make sure your dll is actually being loaded(it could simply be a path issue or a bad dll(you might have not imported/exported the functions).

Find out where the issue is first. It's either in loading the dll, calling the function, or inside the function

Answer (score 1):

I think you have already checked existence of dll.

Now Try this ::

Try to change "Any CPU" to 86 or 64.

Try to run your application as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. [This](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/30429/) link resolved it. The issue was that I was not using _T macro.