# FMI Implementation in VC2015

Tags: implementation, fmi

I am Implementing a co-simulation in vc2015. When I try to load a dll file generated from fmi1.0 using LoadLibraryA, it succeeded. But when I try to load the dll from fmi2.0, it always failed with  the hMod=NULL. Anyone knows how to fix it?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <atlstr.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "fmi2Functions.h"
#include "fmi2FunctionTypes.h"
#include "fmi2TypesPlatform.h"
#include "zh.h"
int main() {
    CString dll_name= "Node1.dll";
    HMODULE hMod;
    char strVer[50] = "";
    strcat_s(strVer, "Node1");
    strcat_s(strVer, "_fmi2InstantiateSlave");
    hMod = LoadLibraryA("Unnamed.dll");


}
```

Comment: Check if the dll is in the search path for loading libraries and use GetLastError to check the reason for the load failure

Comment: For DLL loading issue, you may refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707517/loadlibrary-fails-to-load-dll